# Is it possible to set timezone for a schema - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

Is it possible to set the timezone for one schema? Do not want to set Postgresql(v.12) server level.

Please suggest if any ways to this.

Comment: I'd just like to add some context as to why this is an important question. A schema is generally assumed to be a canonical, serialised representation of the database. However a schema loses some of that reliability if its timestamp column values aren't guaranteed to match the timezone of the server. Hence why being able to specify the data's timezone in a schema is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You can either set the timezone at database level, or at session level (... or directly when accessing a date-like datatype, using the `at time zone` construct).

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> The [TimeZone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) configuration parameter can be set in the file `postgresql.conf`, or in any of the other standard ways described in [Chapter 19](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html). There are also some special ways to set it:
>
> - The SQL command `SET TIME ZONE` sets the time zone for the session. This is an alternative spelling of `SET TIMEZONE TO` with a more SQL-spec-compatible syntax.
> - The `PGTZ` environment variable is used by libpq clients to send a `SET TIME ZONE` command to the server upon connection.

Comment: You should add that it can be set on the user level. Perhaps that solves the OP's unknown problem.

Comment: Please share the commands or settings to set at database level.

Comment: @Venkat: the documentation that I linked in my answer explains how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. The ALTER DATABASE command allows global settings to be overridden on a per-database basis. [ ALTER SYSTEM command provides a SQL-accessible means of changing global defaults; it is functionally equivalent to editing postgresql.conf. The ALTER ROLE command allows both global and per-database settings to be overridden with user-specific values.]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the timezone of a schema (permanently) with:

```
set timezone to 'UTC';
```

Reconnecting and/or restarting my `postgresql` service shows the setting remained. Confirm with: `show timezone;` or `select now();`

Switch to schema2 with: `\c schema2`

I'm using Postgres 12 on Ubuntu.